# Solve for all possible values of $u$

Tags: derivatives

Been struggling to solve this. My derivative is $au-\ln(1+u^2)$ and I need to solve where the derivative is $= 0$. How do I solve $au-ln(1+u^2)=0$? Thank you!

Comment: Certainly, $u= 0$ is a clear solution: $a(0) - \ln(1+ 0^2) = 0 -0 = 0.$

Comment: Yes, 1 solution I found from graphing was u = 0. Wanted to check if I am missing any other solutions.

Comment: Just so you don't engage in the [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you may want to include the function from which you found the derivative, and your work, just to be sure your work is correct.

Comment: There are other solutions that occur for some values of $a$. For example, $a=-1$ yields $1$ solution, $a=-1/2$ yields $3$ solutions, $a=0$ yields $1$ solution, and $a=1/2$ yields 3 solutions again. The roots outside of $u=0$ have no explicit formula and must be computed analytically

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you for the response. how do I compute the roots outside of u=0?

Comment: Depends on your computing environment but it can be done using a scientific calculator or just graphically

Comment: "must be computed analytically" @whpowell96 I'd say, "must be computed numerically". One popular technique, Elliot, is called Newton's Method – you'll find it in every Calculus textbook, and all over the web.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. They certainly must be computed numerically. Newton's method is good but it is hard to get *all* the roots with Newton. Bisection might be a good choice as it's pretty easy to find places where the function has different signs